# Check if a datetime format is valid in Python

Tags: python, datetime

My problem is the following: I want that the User of my program can define the *datetime format* that he will use, for example `'%Y-%m-%d'`, `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` (for more datetime formats see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats).

I want to validate the input of the user, but I do not how (maybe with a regex,
but it's hard to think of all the possibilities).

For example `%ASD-%m-%d` shouldn't be allowed, and `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` yes.

---

All examples that I see on Internet validate a *datetime* in a specific *datetime format*, but I don't what that, I want to validate the *datetime format* itself.

Comment: What's wrong with `"%ASD"`? It is going to print the weekday followed by SD, as in `"WednesdaySD"`. It could be the user's intention.

Comment: ok, maybe is not a good example, think about `sometext that is not a datetime format`

Comment: The only text that is not a valid datetime format is a text that has a % immediately followed by an illegal character. The list of legal format specifiers can be found on the page to which you provided a link. Use regex to search for `'%[^...]"` where `"..."` are all legal specifiers. If there is a match, the format is illegal.

Comment: nice, thank you. if you put that as a answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only text that is not a valid datetime format is a text that has a % immediately followed by an illegal character. The list of legal format specifiers can be found on the page to which you provided a link.

```
LEGAL_SPECS = "aAwdbBmyYHIpMSfzZjUWCxX%GuV"
if re.search(f"(^|[^%])(%%)*%[^{LEGAL_SPECS}]", format): # Invalid
```

P.S. The regex **correctly** reports cases like `'%%X'` where the `%` itself is escaped.